# What's a good way to save all data related to a training run in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I know how to do a few things already:

- Summarise a model with `model.summary()`. But this actually doesn't print everything about the model, just the coarse details.
- Save model with `model.save()` and load model with `keras.models.load_model()`
- Get weights with `model.get_weights()`
- Get the training history from `model.fit()`

But none of these seem to give me a catch all solution for saving everything from end to end so that I can 100% reproduce a model architecture, training setup, and results.

Any help filling in the gaps would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras: How to save model and continue training?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393429/keras-how-to-save-model-and-continue-training). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393429/keras-how-to-save-model-and-continue-training) may also be a viable answer.

Answer (score 0):

model.to_json() can be used to convert model config into json format and save it as a json. 
You can recreate the model from json using model_from_json found in keras.models

Weights can be saved separately using model.save_weights.
Useful in checkpointing your model. Note that model.save saves both of these together. Saving only the weights and loading them back useful when you need to work with the variables used in defining the model. In that case create the model using the code and do model.load_weights.