# is it possible to retrain a previously saved keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

i'm working in a time series prediction using keras and tensorflow. I need to retrain the model with future data. My question is, is this possible in keras and how we can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading a trained Keras model and continue training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666046/loading-a-trained-keras-model-and-continue-training)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

yes.

Save your model as .h5

When you want to train your model, load it again and do a model.fit as normal.

Make sure you do not compile your model after loading it as this will reset your weights.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666046/loading-a-trained-keras-model-and-continue-training) for more info

Comment: Hi, I think you can compile as many times as you want if you keep the same optimizer keeping its state. compile() does not affect the weights  
Here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize
"Keras also supports saving a single HDF5 file containing the model's architecture, weights values, and compile() information." 
load_model() uses compile() with its prev optimizer and loss function and only this.
Check:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model
Plus on fine-tune freezing and then unfreezing layers you use compile() to compile the newly changed code.

Answer (score 9):

I am updating the answer for any new user as it was long time back. if you are using recent `Tensorflow` (such as `TF2.1` or later), then you can retrain the model as mentioned above.

There are two important options (saving in *.tf format and saving in *.h5 format). Saving is similar for both the options but there is a difference in loading the saved model.

### 1. Saving in *.tf format

When you load the saved model, `compile = True` is by default and it will retain the weights without any issue. After loading the saved model, you can retrain as usual using `loaded_model.fit()`.

```
model.save('./MyModel_tf',save_format='tf')
# loading the saved model
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel_tf')

# retraining the model
loaded_model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, validation_data = (x_test,y_test),verbose=1)
```

### 2. Saving in *.h5 format

When you load the saved model, `compile = True` is by default and it will show a warning as follows.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Error in loading the saved optimizer state. As a result, your model is starting with a freshly initialized optimizer
```

The above error means it will use freshly initialized optimizer. After loading the saved model, you can retrain as usual using `loaded_model.fit()`.

```
model.save('./MyModel_h5.h5', save_format='h5')
# loading the saved model
loaded_model_h5 = tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel_h5.h5')
```

Please check detailed [example here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/Keras_model_Continue_training_2.ipynb).

Another most important point is that when you have a custom_objects, then you need to select `compile=False` when you load the model and then compile the model with the custom_objects. This is true for the above two approaches.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this update.
I havent tested this myself, but im a little bit confused. If I understand your answer correctly you are saying that "compile = True" will lead to two different results depending on the file type that is loaded?