# Problems encountered when updating multi-output LSTM?

Tags: lstm

In general, updating a model involves putting a new training set into the model for training. But my question is, in an LSTM with multiple outputs (say, five outputs), I only have new data for one of the outputs, how do I update the model?

I built  neural networks model in keras

Comment: Do you want to train the model AGAIN with all the data, or used your pre-trained model to add more data of only one class?

Comment: Using the pre-trained model to add more data of only one class. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61056066/7396613) out!