# Do I need to compile the model again after loading the model from a ".h5" file in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

can I continue training the model after loading the model like this

`model = keras.models.load_model('path to .h5 file')`

or do i have to use `model.compile()` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.

Save your model as .h5

When you want to train your model, load it again and do a model.fit as normal.

Make sure you do not compile your model after loading it as this will reset your weights.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666046/loading-a-trained-keras-model-and-continue-training) for more info